# Update using JSF

Tags: java, jsf, updates

I have an issue that consists to update an object using JSF, or something better! :/

This is my page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Listagem de mesas do restaurante</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    Escolha uma mesa de sua preferência:<br/>

    <ui:repeat value="#{indexBean.mesas}" var="mesa">
        <br/>Table #{mesa.numero} <h:commandButton id="reservar" value="BloqMesa" action="#{indexBean.reservaMesa(#REFERENCEDTable)}"></h:commandButton><br/>
    </ui:repeat>

</h:body>
```

By the way "Table" is not a table in database, "Table" is the name of the table!

I want to update the table of the actual row of  when i click the commandButton. The real question is what i must to pass in parameters instead #REFERENCEDTable

Ideas??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that *Table* is the English word for *Mesa*, but you should call your classes by their name, not by their translated name.

Answer (score 1):

First, every UICommand component (`<h:commandButton>`, `<h:commandLink>`, etc) must be inside a `<h:form>` that will send the data to the server. You have no form at all, so the action will never be invoked. Note that using a `<h:form>` inside `<ui:repeat>` has a bug in Mojarra implementation. If you're using MyFaces, then there won't be a problem. Still, this seems a case to use a `<h:dataTable>` instead.

Second, you can pass the `mesa` variable as argument to your `IndexBean#reservaMesa` method. Just make sure you have this code (or similar)

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class IndexBean {

    private List<Mesa> mesas;

    public IndexBean() {
    }

    //getters and setters...

    public void reservaMesa(Mesa mesa) {
        //code to update a Mesa
    }
}
```

And you can pass the `mesa` variable to your `reservaMesa` method in the Facelet:

```
<h:commandButton id="reservar" value="BloqMesa"
    action="#{indexBean.reservaMesa(mesa)}" />
```

In the end, you could have this JSF code:

```html
<h:form>
    <!-- replacing ui:repeat by h:dataTable -->
    <h:dataTable value="#{indexBean.mesas}" var="mesa">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Mesas"/>
            </f:facet>
            Table #{mesa.numero}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Actions"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:commandButton id="reservar" value="BloqMesa"
                action="#{indexBean.reservaMesa(mesa)}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:datatable>
</h:form>
```